# Remote sensing and Gis for environmental pollution hazard

Tags: education

Universities that offers GIS and Remote Sensing programs at master or PhD levels.

Comment: Where?  Is moving while you're in school an option?  Would you prefer an online prgram? .................>

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to look at programs that are specific to your interests (e.g. environmental toxicology, env. science, urban planning, landscape ecology, etc), then look at how you can integrate RS/GIS into your research.  You will find that many Universities have excellent programs that are not marketed as RS/GIS degrees, yet produce graduates that are experts in GIS/RS--try not to limit your options.  Perhaps most important is your research focus and where you publish your research.  Publications in journals such as "Remote Sensing of the Environment" will help inform your potential employers of your expertise.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Charles Sturt Unversity (CSU), [Master of GIS and Remote Sensing](http://www.csu.edu.au/courses/postgraduate/gis_remote_sensing/course-overview). As you don't provide any clue about your location I've listed CSU, they were a pioneer of online distance education here in Australia :)